# Persist fields with Setting API

Tags: settings-api, validation

In my admin panel, if I use a sanitizing callback `register_setting()` and the field does not pass through my custom validation, I've been preventing the database from updating by using `return FALSE;` and adding an error with `add_settings_error()`.

How do I return the invalid values back to the form fields that the user submitted, so that they don't have to start all over again?

Answer (score 2):

This a really good question - my suggestion is to use transients. For instance, in your validation callback:

```
 wpse51669_validation_cb($settings){
     //Perform validation checks

     if( $valid ){
        //If settings validate
        return $validate_settings;
     }

     //Otherwise add settings error
     add_settings_error('my-plug-in-settings','error-with-xyz', 'I fell over','error');

     //And add the failed settings to a transient
     set_transient( 'my-plug-in-settings-invalid', $settings, 60);

     return false;
 }
```

Then on your settings page, if the options have been validated - check for the transient, and use the 'failed' settings, if they are found:

```
    if( isset($_GET['settings-updated']) && $_GET['settings-updated'] && get_transient('my-plug-in-settings-invalid') ){
        $options_to_display  = get_transient('my-plug-in-settings-invalid');
        delete_transient('my-plug-in-settings-invalid');    

    }else{
        $options_to_display = get_option('my-plug-in-settings');
    }
```

Comment: is there any way to do this without using the db?

Comment: @DaveKiss - I don't think so, but is there any reason you don't want to use the db?